# Django are method overrides "recognized" in parent class?

Tags: django, methods, save, overriding, slug

I'm relatively new to python and django and I'm just trying to get my head around method overrides and how that effects the way methods work in the parent class.

So I have this parent class a lá:

```
class Parent():

    def save(self):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.get_slug()

    def get_slug(self):
        return slugify(self)
```

and the child class in which I'm going to override the get_slug method as I want to use slugify with its own unicode method (am I right that by calling slugify(self) that he automatically uses the unicode method?).

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' %(self.title, self.season)

    def get_slug(self):
        return slugify(self)
```

What I'm not sure about is how the save method works for a instance of child.
After I created a new child instance (for example in the admin area) does the inherited save method just call the get_slug method in the parent class?

I thought that save would call my overriden get_slug method instead of the original one.
Perhaps it's totally obvious but I don't seem to understand it.

So when I use child.slug in my template I get the outcome of the parent get_slug method.
Only if I use child.get_slug I can get the right outcome.

Could someone explain me how inherited methods interact with overriden methods in a child class.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try it? Put in a few print statements showing where you are, then call `save()` on the child and the parent

Comment: The Child class stands in a manytomany relationship to another class.
If I directly create the child class inside the admin panel (not within the other class) or via shell the slug is correct.
But if I'm going to create an instance of the other class and at the same time create the above child class inside the panel, the slug gets saved wrong.

So does creating an instance of a manytomanyfield does something with the save method?